# Block all SMS sent by email addresses

Tags: sms, email, google-messages

I'm using the stock Google Messages app on Android.  I have started to get spam SMS sent from email addresses with some regularity.
It's all from senders that look like as

- `apps.servmmbership-accntspprt-ntflxregard.dkoeqbjhop9489-838ziyy@jossgandos1.com`
- `authrpf.custs-mailspprtaccnt-vnmo902-00732nvw@parismanagehostingz01.name`

and the message is usually something like "Your [Legitimate Business Name] account has been locked; click this [obvious malicious link] to resolve."

Google's SMS spam filter isn't catching most of these, and because it's trivial for a sender to make a "new" email address, blocking individual addresses has no effect.  The key here is that I get no legitimate SMS messages from email addresses.  All of my legitimate SMS messages come from phone numbers.

Is there a way to disable receipt of SMS messages sent by email addresses?  I want to only receive messages sent by phone numbers.  Barring that, is there a way to not get notifications for ones from email addresses?  I'd prefer to do this without having to switch messaging apps if possible.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is SMS in the strict sense (requiring cell signal to send and receive). Are there any other hints about the sender, like can the sender be clicked to show more info (e.g. Google), or if it's a "[business](https://support.google.com/messages/answer/7513219)" and there's a banner "Sending as [your name]" with the text input saying "Type message" instead of "RCS message" or Text message"?

Comment: disable the chat function

Comment: @alecxs care to elaborate?  How does that help?

Comment: the chat function is resonsible to make it act like a messenger using internet. if you disable it, only true SMS can be received